# Name for Unsolved Problem

Tags: terminology, ceiling-and-floor-functions, open-problem

From the Wikipedia page on the [Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Unsolved_problem):

> The study of [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) has led to an unsolved problem:
>
> Are there any positive integers $k\ge6$ such that
>
> $3^k-2^k\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k\right\rfloor > 2^k-\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k\right\rfloor-2$?
>
> [Mahler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Mahler) has proved there can only be a finite number of such $k$; none are known.

What is the name of this unsolved problem? Note that it is not called *Waring's problem*, but it is derived from the study of Waring's problem.

---

Update: Although I have not spent time researching this question further, I have found a related conjecture called [Euler's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersConjecture.html).

> Define $g(k)$ as the quantity appearing in Waring's problem, then Euler conjectured that
>
> $$g(k) = 2^k + \left\lfloor(\frac{3}{2})^k\right\rfloor-2$$
>
> where $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ is the floor function.

The [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaringsProblem.html) on Waring's problem is useful, but does not name this question's specific problem.

I have yet seen no name for the problem in question.

Comment: Does every open problem have to have a name? (hint: no...)

Comment: @Wojowu I know that not every open problem has a name. I am wondering if *this* one has a name.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Thanks for pointing that out to me, I had messed up the formatting. It should be fixed now.